# How do I get a table value based on the value of another string?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm not to sure if I have used the correct jargon above but what I am trying to do is the follow...
How do I get $author to output a users name (from the mySQL users tabel) on the basis that $author_id of the post, matches the users ID?

```
<?php 
include "inc/mysql-connect.php"; 
$DynamicFeed = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$postCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($postCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $post = $row["post"];
    $author_id = $row["author_id"];
    $author = $row["author_id"];
    $type = $row["type"];
    $date_posted = $row["date_posted"];
    $DynamicFeed .= "<div class=\"item\"><img class=\"img-type\" align=\"left\"       src=\"img/$type.jpg\"> <p><a href=\"droplet.php?id=$id\"><b>$title</b></a><br />by <a    href=\"profile.php?id=$author_id\">$author</a> on $date_posted<br /><br /> $post</p>    </div>";
}
} else {
$DynamicFeed = "It would appear that there ar'nt any Droplets here...";
}
?>
```

Comment: use a `JOIN` in your SQL statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JOIN statement as follows:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT posts.*,users.name FROM posts LEFT JOIN users on posts.author_id=users.id ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: Ah Awesome, Lemme just give this a test :)

Comment: Currently this will fail as you would also need to change `ORDER BY id DESC` to reference the table name like `ORDER BY post.id DESC` since `id` alone is ambiguous.

Comment: @danielb - Back, Oh it works perfectly with 'ORDER BY id DESC' :3 Should I change it to the updated code anyways? Is it a tidier way of doing it? :P

Comment: If you had the column "id" in both tables, you would need to indicate which table's id you wanted to order by. If it works as-is, it means you don't have "id" in both tables. I would add it in anyway.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. One last thing before I bump this up as the answer. How would I do exactly the same thing but with this query?
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT posts.*,users.name FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.author_id=users.id WHERE posts.id='$id' LIMIT 1");

Comment: Brilliant! You Sir are the bee's knee's. Thank you very much @danielb

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT posts.*, users.username FROM posts JOIN users ON author_id = users.id ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: Currently this will fail as you would also need to change `ORDER BY id DESC` to reference the table name like `ORDER BY post.id DESC` since `id` alone is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should do this directly in your query (not in while cycle), by joining user table:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN <user-table> ON <user-table>.id=author_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Then you get your data directly in $row array. You may need to add aliases, if you have same column names in both tables.